# Returning std::span from a function

Tags: c++, c++20

Yesterday I started to use `std::span` because it's really handy, so I wanted to know if I'm getting `std::span` out of function correctly. Is it correct?

```cpp
std::span<std::uint8_t const> span1;
if (read_data(&span1))
    return 0;

// function
int read_data(std::span<std::uint8_t const>* output)
{
    uint8_t* address = ...
    size_t size = ...

    *output = { address, size };

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Why use pointers instead of references?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Because then the potential for modification is obvious on the *caller side*. That's a compelling enough reason (and why some style guides include using pointers for output parameters).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes because of what the guy said. Just so the caller would know that it actually returns the value out of the function.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I always thought const versus non-const references would be good enough hint about it, especially together with a little documentation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - You can't tell just from `read_data(span1)` is if takes it by a const reference, a modifying reference or even by value. Documentation is nice and all, but one shouldn't have to constantly jump around to understand a simple line of code. That's why conventions exist. To improve communication between us sacks of meat the write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct?

A bit hard to tell when you omit the most important bit and replace it by a pair of `...`.

Assuming the buffer is not of automatic storage duration and persists beyond the function call... Then yes, it's not immediately wrong. But if you intend for the span to *own* the buffer, you'd soon get into trouble.

A span is meant to represent a non-owning reference type, like a raw pointer. Owning raw pointers are problematic in the general case, and a span would be no different.

If on the other hand you only use the span to grant a view of the buffer (and there is no lifetime issues), then it's a perfectly legitimate use of `std::span`. It's its intended purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In my case, it's about owning the pointer. What should I use in that case?

Comment: But wait, it's also not automatic storage duration and persists beyond the function call, which means it should be okay?

Comment: @nop - A static buffer would be okay (because the span doesn't own it). If you allocate, you need to use a proper handle type. `std::unique_ptr` as a default is still as good as any. You can also wrap it in a custom class to represent size information.

Comment: I dunno. The memory is being allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: @nop - That isn't a deal breaker. A unique_ptr holding a custom deleter will work for mallocated memory.  For example https://godbolt.org/z/roz33d89K